# jsPDF HTML2Canvas + HTML + Images cut off capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

Is there a way to adjust the width and height when capturing with canvas?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        var options = {
            background: '#fff'
        };
        html2canvas(jQuery("#pdf"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
                doc.save('results.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use configuration options: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

width >> DEFAULT: Element width - The width of the canvas

height >> DEFAULT:Element height - The height of the canvas